# How can I reduce power draw while suspended?

Tags: bios, power, power-management, battery-life, suspend

My new XPS 13 has pretty poor battery life while suspended. I've had to switch to hibernating. Is there any way to tweak bios or something to reduce suspended power draw? It has Fedora installed, though I'm guessing that doesn't matter.

Comment: https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-cpu-c-states-power-saving-modes/ introduces Intel's innovations in power management. However, since there are over two dozen different XPS 13s at https://pilot.search.dell.com/laptops/XPS%2013, I must ask: Which XPS 13? Please advise the model number from the serial number plate, or the Dell Service Tag, so we can get relevant details. Please add that by clicking on `edit` above and to the left and add that to the original post. The OS matters very much, BTW; different OS have differing power management capabilities.

Comment: Consider hibernation.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/7hmv4u/fedora_27_hibernation/  If you have a lot of RAM, it may take a long time to write it all to disk, so test it out with a lot of programs running.  You don't want to chuck it into a bag and do a lot of banging around while it's saving state.

Answer (score 2):

Go into your BIOS and then select power management. Check to see if there are different suspend states. Choosing a higher suspend state, if available, will conserve more power. However, your machine will take longer to wake.